# Python Programming for Data Science For Loop support

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

Hi everyone I have this task:
Write a python program that takes two numeric inputs x and y.

a) [5 pts] The program should take numeric inputs continuously.

b) [10 pts] The program should ensure the range of x and y is between 0 and 1. If either one of the input values is out of range, smaller than 0 or greater than 1, then the program should quit.

c) [10 pts] Implement XOR gate, where the program returns 1 if both x and y values are different; otherwise, it returns 0.

The program should work for floating-point values.

For example,

If x = .3 and y = .3, then xor output should be 0

If x = .6 and y = .3, then xor output should be 1

If x = .3 and y = .6, then xor output should be 1

If x = .6 and y = .6, then xor output should be 0

So far I have done this but I still keep getting errors

```
x=float(input("enter x: "))

y=float(input("enter y : "))
while True:

  if(x>=0 and x<=1) and (y>=0 and y<=1):
        def XOR (x, y):
            if x != y:
              return 1
            else:  return 0
  print(XOR(x,y))
continue 
  elif(x>=0 and x<=1) and (y>=0 and y<=1): 
        break
I get this error
 File "<ipython-input-337-80599671f24c>", line 13
    elif(x>=0 and x<=1) and (y>=0 and y<=1):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: [What's wrong with your current code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: you try printing xor. But that's not defined anywhere.

Comment: Also what's the error that you get currently?

Comment: @jimbob: In the future, please [format your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/133817) (in this case, Perry did it for you). The "{}" button in the editor toolbar will format selected text as code. The editor toolbar has more information and tips on formatting.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues. x can't be both < 0 and > 1. Same for y. You need to try or. Also there's no return from second if or break. But it could be the indentation as I understand. I tried little simpler implementation. Try this out.

```
def xor(x, y):
    if x != y:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def main():
    x = float(input("Enter x: "))
    y = float(input("Enter y: "))
    if x < 0 or x > 1 or y < 0 or y > 1:
        print("Invalid input")
        return
    print(xor(x, y))
    if xor(x, y) == 1:
        main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Also tried fixing your code and seems to work now:

```
x=float(input("enter x: "))

y=float(input("enter y : "))

if(x>0 and x<1) and (y>0 and y<1):
  def XOR (x, y):
    if x != y:
      return 1
    else:  return 0
  print(XOR(x,y))
```

Comment: If you're not sure what's wrong with the code, you should post a comment asking for clarification. One cannot say this answer is useful for solving the problem, because the problem has not been made well-defined.

Comment: Hi Perry thanks for your new code this one works great however when I put 10 as the value for x it still runs. for the code to work under the condition the code should break if a value over 1 or under 0 is put in. Thanks again for your help

Comment: I am getting an error when I try to add a break statement it says break outside loopx=float(input("enter x: "))

y=float(input("enter y : "))
if(x<0 and x>1) and (y<0 and y>1):
  break
elif(x>0 and x<1) and (y>0 and y<1):
  def XOR (x, y):
    if x != y:
      return 1
    else:  return 0
    
print(XOR(x,y))

Comment: add an else instead. I've updated the code.

Comment: Or better reverse the condition, as I do in my main function.

Comment: the task says that if input is over 1 or less then 0 loop should quit. do you have any suggestions for that everything else is good x=float(input("enter x: "))

y=float(input("enter y : "))

if(x>0 and x<1) and (y>0 and y<1):
  def XOR (x, y):
    if x != y:
      return 1
    else:  return 0
else:
  print("Invalid input")
    
print(XOR(x,y)) this works but when i put 8 as x and 4 as y it does say invalid input but it should just quit the loop no?

Comment: there's no loop in play here? Can you elaborate further? Like what are you trying to iterate in a loop? It's not clear.

Comment: Because the input is continuous meaning even after the output the code should request another input I am assuming a loop would be required for that

Comment: I got it now. It needs to run recursively.

Comment: Yes and also  "If either one of the input values is out of range, smaller than 0 or greater than 1, then the program should quit."

Comment: Updated the solution. This should do.

Comment: Thank you this works much better. however it still is not recursive in terms of allowing me to put another input in afterwards, also is there a way to add a comment or print that says "invalid input" if the entry is incorrect for example if I put 15 as x and 12 as y

Comment: I am trying this x=float(input("enter x: "))

y=float(input("enter y : "))
while True:

  if(x>=0 and x<=1) and (y>=0 and y<=1):
   def XOR (x, y):
      if x != y:
        return 1
      else:  return 0
  print(XOR(x,y))
continue 
  else: 
    break but I get the error unexpected indent

Comment: Can you update the same in your original question in a code block to give a better idea of indentation?

Answer (score 0):

While the loop will get input until the input is empty. This might work

```
def XOR(x, y):
    if x != y:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

while True:
    str=input("Enter X and Y:")
    if str=="":
        break
    x,y=map(float,str.split())
    if (x<0 and x>1) and (y<0 and y>1):
        break
    else:
        print(XOR(x,y))
```